# how to display child along with grand child?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting to all grand child id's title but i am not getting child id's title please help me to getting both

here is my query:

```
SELECT g.title  FROM object_data a,`object_reference` b,`tree` c,`object_reference` d,`tree` e,`object_reference` f,`object_data` g WHERE a.`obj_id` = b.`obj_id` AND b.`ref_id` = c.`parent` AND c.`child` = d.`ref_id` AND d.`ref_id` = e.`parent` AND e.`child` = f.`ref_id` AND f.`obj_id` = g.`obj_id`AND g.type='tst' AND a.obj_id=3217
```

here is sample data:
table object_data:

```
obj_id | type | title 
-------+------+------
3217   |crs   |it 
3221   |grp   |xyz 
3228   |tst   |test 
3264   |tst   |test3
```

table object_reference:

```
ref_id | obj_id 
-------+---------
337    |3217       
338    |3221      
343    |3228 
371    |3264
```

table tree:

```
tree | child | parent 
-----+-------+------
1    |338    |337 
2    |343    |338 
3    |371    |337
```

here is expected result:

```
title
-----
test
test3
```

but am getting only test3 as result from the above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for all the titles of IDs who do not have childs because you are not interested in seeing XYZ which is a parent of test.
If my assumption is right, following query helps get your desired result.

```
select title from object_data c , object_reference d
where c.obj_id=d.obj_id
and d.ref_id in (select a.child from tree a, tree b
where a.child =b.parent(+)
and b.parent is null);
```

Result:

TITLE

test

test3

To display all the tests under a given course(root of the tree), following query works

```
with parent_child (child, parent) as
(
select child, parent from tree 
union all
select t.child, parent_child.parent 
from parent_child , tree t where t.parent=parent_child.child)
select c.title from parent_child a,object_data c , object_reference d
where c.obj_id=d.obj_id
and d.ref_id=a.child
and parent=337 --Provide the root id
and type='tst'; --removing this would display all the nodes of a tree, including XYZ
```

Comment: hi avani thanks for reply where can i write c.obj_id=3217

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on your requirement as to why you need to mention or hardcode the obj_id ?

Comment: yes i have courses and those courses have groups and tests .some tests are directley under the course and some tests are under the groups which are under the course ...soo my main conclusion is when i write a query with course id i need to get all tests

Comment: am new to sql i am unable to solve this properly please help me to solve it

Comment: yes xyz is child of it and test is child of xyz... above tables with tree child and parent

Comment: am getting error like unrecognized statement type(near WITH)

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not clear to understand, try this:

```
select a.title from object_data as a 
         inner join object_reference b on a.obj_id = b.obj_id
         inner join tree as c on b.ref_id = c.child
```

If this is not what you wanted, please, specify it better.

Comment: thanks for resonse.my question is  when i write below query SELECT g.title  FROM object_data a,`object_reference` b,`tree` c,`object_reference` d,`tree` e,`object_reference` f,`object_data` g WHERE a.`obj_id` = b.`obj_id` AND b.`ref_id` = c.`parent` AND c.`child` = d.`ref_id` AND d.`ref_id` = e.`parent` AND e.`child` = f.`ref_id` AND f.`obj_id` = g.`obj_id`AND g.type='tst' AND a.obj_id=3217
 am getting only grand child (test3) not getting child (test)

Comment: Do you really NEED to use your query this way?